How to store Environmental Variables in Snowflake?
I have one use case where I aim to store multiple variables in a Key and Value format in Snowflake only. These variables need to be accessible within Snowflake SQL Statements, and I intend to maintain their persistence across all sessions.
To provide clarity, here's an example scenario:
# set variable once in sesson 1    
query_runtime_threshold = 30000

#Access variable value in session 2 & 3 and more.
SELECT * FROM QUERY_HISTORY() WHERE exection_time >= :query_runtime_threshold 

Initially, I tried it by creating a User Defined Function (UDF) and storing the variables in a secure table. However, UDFs do not permit the execution of queries and the return Query result. Instead of UDF we can use Procedure but that procedure will not be able call within SQL Statement.
Subsequently, I explored the option of using Snowflake Identifiers, but I discovered that they are session-specific. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a suitable type to store the variable at the environment level, enabling its use across multiple sessions.
I am not in favor of writing nested SQL to get the value from the secure table wherever it require. Is there any other way that I can use

Hi - why do you think that a UDF does not permit the execution of a query? There’s an example of one here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-scalar-functions

Thank you so much @NickW, I have missed it somehow, I need rest now. :-)

There are many ways of working with variables, and some known limitations to them. With regards to an UDF, this below works fine. Note that $$ is in there for SnowSQL. Not needed for Worksheets.
First is the definition of the UDF; and then simply calling it with your variable as input. Do note that you can also use an select statement as input for an variable, and other ways. As variables are limited in nature to 256 bytes, sometimes It's better to use an reference table.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION QUERY_HISTORY_BY_THRESHOLD(runtime_threshold INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE (
    QUERY_ID STRING,
    EXECUTION_TIME INTEGER,
    QUERY_TEXT STRING,
    DATABASE_NAME STRING,
    SCHEMA_NAME STRING,
    QUERY_TYPE STRING,
    START_TIME TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3),
    END_TIME TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT
        QUERY_ID,
        EXECUTION_TIME,
        QUERY_TEXT,
        DATABASE_NAME,
        SCHEMA_NAME,
        QUERY_TYPE,
        START_TIME,
        END_TIME
    FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY())
    WHERE EXECUTION_TIME >= runtime_threshold
$$;

-- Set the runtime threshold in a variable
SET query_runtime_threshold = 30000;

-- Call the UDF with the threshold variable
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(QUERY_HISTORY_BY_THRESHOLD($query_runtime_threshold));

